# Query results contain null fields even when I've specified "is not null" on the field

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I'm doing a `LEFT JOIN` on to get all records from the first table regardless if there's a match from the second table.

I discovered that sometimes `NULL` comes back on the join column.  I put in a where clause to filter out records that have `NULL` in the join column and yet I'm still seeing these records.

What do I need to change in the `SQL` below in order to filter out records that have a `NULL` in the join column?

```
select
folders.FolderId,
folders.lastUpdated,
folder.FolderName,
folder.FolderParentID
from dbo.xsdl_Folder folder
left join dbo.Folders folders
on folder.FolderID = folders.FolderID
where folder.FolderID is not null;
```

Comment: Remove where clause and put "AND" try

Comment: @AshReva - still seeing nulls after replacing "where" with "and"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your FolderId is coming back NULL and you're intentions are to retrieve all data from the Folder table and only those matching records from the Folders table, then it looks like you need to change your query to use folder.FolderId instead of folders.FolderId in your SELECT statement:

```
select
   folder.FolderId,
   folders.lastUpdated,
   folder.FolderName,
   folder.FolderParentID
from dbo.xsdl_Folder folder
   left join dbo.Folders folders
      on folder.FolderID = folders.FolderID
```

Alternatively, if you're looking into removing all NULL values from your results, then don't use `LEFT JOIN`, rather use `INNER JOIN`:

```
select
   folders.FolderId,
   folders.lastUpdated,
   folder.FolderName,
   folder.FolderParentID
from dbo.xsdl_Folder folder
   inner join dbo.Folders folders
      on folder.FolderID = folders.FolderID
```

The purpose of the `LEFT JOIN` is to return NULL values from the 2nd table, in this case, dbo.Folders.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson -- I think it was the folders.FolderId vs. the folder.FolderId in his SELECT statement if I had to guess :)

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - I wonder if it has to do with the driver I'm using...my query is against a SQL Server database using JDBC.  Do you think that connecting to a SQL Server database using JDBC could influence how JOIN is understood underneath the covers?

Comment: @ZackMacomber No, probably not... I misread your query as `where folders.FolderID is not null;`... but it actually was `where folder.FolderID is not null;`, so your original query isn't logically the same as an `inner join`.

Comment: oops - I see where I went wrong - I should be using `folder.FolderID` as you stated in your 2nd statement...I hate getting burned by 1 character!

Comment: @ZackMacomber -- no worries -- glad we got it working for you!  Best of luck.

Comment: Just to be accurate...the 2nd block of code is what actually brings back the correct result set...could you update your answer to not include the 1st block as I get 334 records in my DB when I run the 1st select statement as opposed to 3,222 records when I run the 2nd select statement...just want to make sure that the next guy (which could be me ;) can get the correct result set with as little trouble as possible...

Comment: @ZackMacomber -- how's that?  I can remove the other part altogether, but it does seem potentially relevant for future users.  Let me know :)